# Python: convert u'001' to 001

Tags: python

Does someone know how to convert this result: `u'001'` to `001` to put it in a variable path: `Z:\ProjectPath\001\`
In advance, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: how about `int(u'001')`?

Comment: @Michael: no, converting it to an integer would give `1`, and the zeros are essential as it is a path!

Comment: i forget to tell that u'001 is a variable, it can be also 005, 010 , 056, 589 ...

Comment: u'001' is already a string you should be able to insert it as is in the path string ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use format to achieve you purpose

```
>>> IN = u'001'
>>> OUT = "Z:\\ProjectPath\\{}\\".format(IN)
>>> print(OUT)
Z:\ProjectPath\001\
```

According to @hop's suggestion, you can use os.path to compose your path.

```
>>> OUT = os.path.join("Z:", os.sep, "ProjectPath", "{}".format(IN))
```

Comment: Thank a lot Kir Chou,

Comment: and if i use my variable as an integer (my entry is 1, i whant to get: 001)     
EpisodeName = `cmds.intField("EpisodeName", query = True, value = True)`    
print EpisodeName #result: 24  
'{:03}'.format(EpisodeName)   
give me this error:  
# Error: ValueError: file <maya console> line 17: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier # 
how can i format a variable of an integer?

Comment: use `os.path` for path operations.

Comment: thanks again Kir Chou :)

Comment: `format` support **int** too, please try `"{}".format(1234)`

Comment: and hop too of course, sorry i'm new in this forum!

Comment: @Gnn, Welcome to SO. If you have solved your question, had no advanced question and do not expect better solutions, it will be nice to click the check mark of the answer for each question you asked in this forum.